# Who's responsible for creating associated has_many model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, polymorphic-associations

I have "quick add" form that is responsible for creating a **Foobar**. Once it submits/saves, you are returned to the form to add the next Foobar. I now have polymorphic **Tasks** that I'm wanting to add to the Foobar as it's being created. The Tasks require no details in this context, so I've opted to have a checkbox on the form that says "Do This Task". If checked when the form is submitted, I'd like to have a Task created and associated to the Foobar.

Doing it isn't hard, but I'm struggling to find what seems to be the "right" way of doing it.

**Option 1:** The Foobar accepts_nested_attributes_for Tasks so I can create a nested form, but there's really nothing to nest. The checkbox doesn't represent a valid field on the Task, only that I want the task created. I could use @foobar.build_task and put some hidden fields in the form for the task, but I'd have to use JS voodoo to prevent the fields from submitting if the checkbox isn't checked. This just seems dirty and wrong.

**Option 2:** I can put some logic in FoobarController#create that looks for the checkbox and builds the task onto the Foobar before save. The issue here is that the Task is polymorphic and could be tied to other things, too. There may even be multiple "types" of tasks tied to the single Foobar being created. This solution is better than Option 1, I think, but isn't very DRY. Any such logic in the controller would end up being duplicated in the controllers for other taskable things.

**Option 3:** Have a before_save on Foobar that looks for the presence of a pseudo-field called "create_task" and then builds the task. This moves the duplication out of controllers and into taskable models, but it's no more a duplication than the duplicated "has_many :tasks" line in each model. Still, it doesn't seem like it's the model's job to look for such a field and act on it.

so.... I'd really appreciate some thoughts.

***UPDATE #1: A little extra info...***

A Task also has a creator and an assignee, both are users in the system. A creator should be automatically assigned based on a current_user method, which of course is available in the View and Controller, but not the model. I think the excludes right away the possibility of the answer being purely model based (such as option 3). I think it also hints at the answer not being view based (such as option 1), as the user should be set server side where it can't be tampered with. So perhaps the answer lies somewhere in the Controller? Perhaps some sort of helper method to wrap up the logic to be duplicated in each Controller that handles taskable things?

***UPDATE #2: My current leaning...***

I spent some time speaking with a respected developer friend and am further convinced the answer is closest to option 2. Both the view and model seem wrong. The controller makes sense, but the main problem is the potential of repeated code. I think the answer is going to be in finding the best way to factor out the controller code that handles the attachment of Tasks (or other polymorphic things like comments, file uploads, etc.) to the object that controller is responsible for. When I have a solution I'm happy with, I'll try and post it here. Thanks for the input, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something that is a derivative of **Option 1**. There are actually two solution I might use though.

### Solution 1

This one is much simpler but isn't quite as extensible.

Using the existing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks`, make sure you have this option though:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destory => true
```

Then in your in your form use (assuming `task_collection` is a collection of prebuilt tasks):

```
<%= form_for(@record) do |form| %>
   ...
   <%= form.fields_for :tasks, task_collection do |task_fields| %>
     <%= task_fields.check_box(:_destroy,{},0,1) %> Do This Task
   <% end %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Basically this is going to take `Task` association-object and if the box is checked persist it, otherwise mark it for destruction. This should prevent any so called "*JS voodoo*" since any such logic is handled in the model.

### Solution 2

The **other** option, but the much more complex option, I might use is to:

```
def tasks_attributes=(tasks_attributes)
```

Doing that in each applicable model(or an included module) then handling all the tasks attributes when they're submitted from the form.

It involves handling the `task_attributes` in the model. which means you have to build your forms a certain way and some other subtle details. But using this approach you wouldn't have to build a `Task` object then destroy it, you could just handle the submission data to create `tasks`.

The details of doing this is pretty in-depth and not something I really want to go into. But you seem resourceful enough that just knowing it's there could help you out.

More info on this is in the [`fields_for` documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/58e48d5292242f000dc8a87fdbb1c0ccdcf286d8/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L286) and the [`accepts_attributes_for` implementation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: I didn't know about the :allow_destroy option or the related :_destroy field, so thanks for that!

Comment: Oops - submitted the previous comment prematurely via "Enter" key. I updated my question to include some thoughts on why I suspect the answer isn't in the view, though. I'm partially inclined to agree with your Solution 1, but it seems to put too much responsibility on the view. I am familiar with the `tasks_attributes=` idea, but I think it still suffers the symptoms I mention in my updates to the question and in my response to @user1438190. As mentioned before, I know several ways to do this, but really just looking for the cleanest one. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan, In relation to option 1, I've used the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem by Ryan Bates.

Comment: Thanks, @Josh. As mentioned in my update, I still suspect the answer is in the controller, not the view (for which that gem may be useful would) or the model.

Comment: The way you're describing it reminds me a little bit of looking for a solution for the wrong problem. No matter what you're going to be injecting the `current_user` into something at the controller level. The real question is how should one pass that information onto the current model. If the problem really is beyond that I don't understand the problem well enough to help, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I would go like this:

```
class Foobar
  has_many :tasks
  attr_accessor :add_task
  after_create :create_task, if: add_task == true

  private
  def create_task
    tasks.create(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is basically a slightly cleaner version of Option 3. I still can't shake the feeling that creation of the task shouldn't be coupled with the foobar. One thing I didn't mention that reenforces my concern is that the task tracks the current user as it's creator. A current_user method is available to controllers/views, but isn't (and shouldn't be) available within models. This seems to be a "code smell" indicating a problem with that way of solving the problem within the model. I still feel the answer is somewhere upstream from the model.